# Login Api with Meta_key and Meta_value

Tags: custom-field, login

How i can make login where the parameter and the value is i get from meta_key and meta_value where have same post_id.. i ve been try, but nothing work.

here my code now :

```
//* Login Driver *//
$command = $_GET['command'];
switch ($command) {
    case 'login_driver':
    if(empty($_REQUEST['email']) OR empty($_REQUEST['password'])) {
           $data = array( "api_status" => 0, "api_message" => "Wrong Email Or Password");
           echo  json_encode($data);
        } elseif( $_REQUEST['email'] == get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'email', true) AND $_REQUEST['password'] == get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'password', true) ) {
           $loop = new WP_Query( 
                array(
                        'post_type'    => 'drivers',
                        'meta_query'    => array(
                            'relation'      => 'AND',
                            array(
                                'key'       => 'username',
                                'value'     => $_REQUEST['email'],
                                'compare'   => '='
                            ),
                            array(
                                'key'       => 'password',
                                'value'     => $_REQUEST['password'],
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ); 
            $data = array("api_status" => 1, "api_message" => "success", "result" => "");
            if( $loop->have_posts() ) :
                while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                    $data['result'][] = array(
                        "id"        => get_the_ID(),
                        "post_name" => get_the_title(),
                        "username"  => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'username', true),
                        "password"  => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'password', true),
                        "email"     => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'email', true),
                        "phone"     => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'phone', true),
                    );
                endwhile;
            endif;
            echo  json_encode($data);
        }elseif($_REQUEST['email'] != get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'email', true) OR $_REQUEST['password'] != get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'password', true)){
           $data = array( "api_status" => 0, "api_message" => "Wrong Email Or Password");
           echo  json_encode($data);
        }else{
            $data = array( "api_status" => 0, "api_message" => "Wrong Email Or Password");
           echo  json_encode($data);
        }
break;
}
```

and this my table :

[image]

have someone help me how i can solve my problem ? or can someone give me solution for me ? because now iam stuck now..

Answer (score 0):

To log a user in you really only need the user's `ID`. Based on your info you should be able to obtain it from the `username` field.

```
// Get User object
$user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );

// Clear any auth cookies
wp_clear_auth_cookie();

// Log the user in
wp_set_current_user( $user->ID );
wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID );
```

On a non-login page you could probably refresh right after;

```
header("Refresh:0");
exit();
```

Now that the hard part is out of the way, it comes down to where you're getting your `username` from.

Most people don't store `username`/`password` in plaintext on `post_metadata`. But even then, and you're making a whole loop query for login data, you're still going to have to settle on logging in a single user. So the whole `$data['result'][]=` doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: iam sorry sir, iam still confuse how to apply thats condition to my code, sir may u make it more simple or can u do in my code to ?

i think its will more help me thank you sir